# SELinux blocks execution of native executable on Android

Tags: java, android, exec, processbuilder, selinux

I am trying to run my own native executable. The code looks like this:

```
String[] command = {"/data/user/0/org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test/files/smoproc"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = builder.start();
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test/files/smoproc": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
    at org.smowsoft.systeminformation.ExampleInstrumentedTest.testRun(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:113)
    ... 29 trimmed
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 31 more
```

I also tried to run the executable from native code like this:

```
char* lArgs[] = {0, 0};
lArgs[0] = new char[8];
strcpy(lArgs[0], "smoproc");
int result = execv("/data/user/0/org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test/files/smoproc", lArgs);
```

But execv() returns -1 and errno is set to 13 (EACCESS).

The mode of the executable is set to 0777.

Wher I run dmesg from shell I can see that SELinux blocks the execution:

```
[15194.067480] type=1400 audit(1649841626.956:417509): avc: granted { execute } for comm="roidJUnitRunner" name="smoproc" dev="dm-5" ino=131258 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file app=org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test
[15194.070245] type=1400 audit(1649841626.956:417510): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for comm="roidJUnitRunner" path="/data/data/org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test/files/smoproc" dev="dm-5" ino=131258 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=org.smowsoft.systeminformation.nativelib.test
```

API level is 30. I tried it on multiple devices. Does this mean it is not possible to run native executables on API level 30 and higher?

Comment: Have you set the executable bits of the file via `chmod`? On some Android versions `/data/local/tmp` is not bowsable for apps. Therefore I would recommend to use the full path `/data/local/tmp/smoproc` as command.

Comment: @Robert I tried this. Now I get a different error (see my edit in the post).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : by order of preference, you could try the following :

- The best policy would probably be to put your executable in the standard location on your device ;
- Else, you can try telling selinux to allow executing things from wherever your binary currently is ;
- If this fails, you can try running audit2why to get a suggestion from selinux on how to allow your program to run ;
- If security is not a concern, maybe just set selinux to permissive while you try running your program.

The long version :

Selinux adds a layer of security over your filesystem, so if you want your program to work with selinux, at some point you will have to deal with it directly.

[This article on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1032597/selinux-is-preventing-from-execute-access-on-the-file-centos) seems like it might be related to your problem. If your executable is not located in a "standard" place (where your system expects to find binaries), then selinux is likely to prevent execution. The serverfault source explains this can be fixed either with the following selinux command (if I read your path to your application correctly) :

```
chcon -R -t bin_t /data/local/tmp
```

or by putting your application wherever your other binaries are stored.

If the above command solves your problem, you can update the policy permanently by running (still adapted from serverfault) :

```
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/data/local/tmp(/.*)?"
restorecon -r -v /data/local/tmp
```

If the above does not work, selinux comes with an audit tool that gives reasons for the denials and that is called audit2why. Running :

```
audit2why -a
```

will usually provide you with a solution to allow that specific thing that was denied. It is not always a good idea to try and implement those solutions, though.

Finally, if security is not a concern, you can always set selinux to permissive on your device (even temporarily to get your program to run) :

```
semanage permissive -a bin_t
```