Executive Binary on Android Studio App Target API 34 Permission Problem
I have an executable binary file named "main." I'm trying to run this binary using Android Studio's exec and ProcessBuilder. It works on API levels 28 and below, but when I target API 29 or higher, it returns a "permission denied" error.
To resolve this, I attempted various solutions, including setting permissions with chmod and adjusting file access settings. Despite these efforts, the issue persisted. I expected these methods to grant the necessary permissions and allow the binary to execute, but they did not work.
I suspect the issue is due to security changes introduced in API 29 and above. Starting with API 29, Android has implemented stricter security measures, such as Scoped Storage, which restricts direct access to the filesystem. Additionally, executing binaries in the app's data directory has been restricted for non-shell users.
I hope someone could help me! 

You forget that Android also uses SELinux to restrict user accounts/apps. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/70741783/150978

Is there a specific function / API that your executable is calling when it gets this permission denied / security error? If we knew some code that had the problem, readers would be in a better position to suggest a cause or a solution.

The complete error message and entire stack trace may also help people discover the cause of your problem.
